# Is Keras useful for professionals?

Tags: keras

I know that Keras is developed for quick deployment. Is it just for beginners or also useful in industry for professionals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keras is used in academia (see [google scholar citations](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?cites=17868569268188187229&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) of Keras as a proxy for academy adoption) and hobbyists (see [github stars](https://github.com/fchollet/keras) or [google results for *keras* in www.kaggle.com](https://www.google.es/webhp?#q=site:www.kaggle.com+keras) as proxies for hobbyist adoption).

It was [recently](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/5jg7b8/p_deep_learning_for_coders18_hours_of_lessons_for/dbhaizx/) bundled together with Google's tensorflow.

It is also used in industry, at least for prototyping (I know because I use it!), but I have found no source to back this statement.

Comment: Prototyping is a very important task in industry, and you need tools to quickly build this prototypes. You may not use it to implement the final product, but it is still useful nevertheless.

Comment: What happens _after_ prototyping is done? How is a prototype productionized?